# Can I run just tests inside a subfolder of the test folder in Rails (Minitest)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake, minitest

Hard to believe this hasn't been asked before, but I couldn't find it.

I am trying to run only my Capybara tests who are inside their own folder `test/integration/capybara`. 
I tried to do it by `bundle exec rake test test/integration/capybara` but it always runs all the tests under `test`.
In the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) it says I can invoke just my integration tests by `rake test:integration` which works. But `rake test test:integration:capybara` doesn't.
Is it possible to go deeper than one level?

Comment: Hey @Flip! Any progress with the issue?

Comment: Hey EugZol. I started rewriting all of my tests. So yes and no. I will definitely work through all the answers I got here on SO regarding that topic, including yours. Thank you already for helping!

Answer (score 4):

You can build your own rake task. Add that to `lib/tasks/test_capybara.rake`:

```
namespace :test do
  namespace :integration do
    Rake::TestTask.new('capybara') do |t|
      t.libs = ['lib','test']
      t.pattern = 'integration/capybara/**/*_test.rb'
      t.verbose = true
    end
  end
end
```

Then run `rake test test:integration:capybara`.